# flutter: Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host,

Tags: flutter, dart

i run my application using localhost and my phone and laptop connect to the same WiFi. i did check the ip address but why i still have this error? I had used the localhost before this but nothing go wrong. it just happen

```
Launching lib\main.dart on GT I9300 in debug mode...
E/flutter (14807): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (14807): <br />
E/flutter (14807): ^
E/flutter (14807):
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1261:9)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:926:22)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #3      _parseJson  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:31:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #4      JsonDecoder.convert  (dart:convert/json.dart:505:36)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #5      JsonCodec.decode  (dart:convert/json.dart:153:41)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #6      jsonDecode  (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (14807): #7      _TukarKataLaluanState.tukar[39;49m
E/flutter (14807): <asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248mE/flutter (14807): #8      _TukarKataLaluanState.boxform.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #9      _InkResponseState._handleTap[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #10     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #11     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #15     GestureArenaManager.sweep[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #21     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #22     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #24     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (14807): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)[39;49m
E/flutter (14807):
E/flutter (16045): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60710
E/flutter (16045):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60720
E/flutter (18300):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60721
E/flutter (18300):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60722
E/flutter (18300):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60727
E/flutter (18300):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60732
E/flutter (18300):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60745
E/flutter (18300):
E/flutter (18300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: No route to host, errno = 113, address = 172.20.10.3, port = 60750
E/flutter (18300):
```

Answer (score 0):

On your emulator(or mobile device) navigate to

Settings > Developer options > Wireless Debugging

Open it and enable Wireless debugging.

Make sure the device is connected to the same network as your development machine is, then you will be able to communicate from your emulator or physical device to the server you host locally at that ip:port.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device with wireless debugging and use endpoints as "http://yourIp:port"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when I connected to wi-fi but internet was not available on that wi-fi connection.